# How to lazily read big Excel 2007 files with Apache POI

Tags: memory, apache-poi, lazy-evaluation

I'd like to read a big Excel 2007 file with Apache POI. [Quick start guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) states that a `File` should be used to conserve memory.

> When opening a workbook, either a .xls HSSFWorkbook, or a .xlsx
>   XSSFWorkbook, the Workbook can be loaded from either a File or an
>   InputStream. Using a File object allows for lower memory consumption,
>   while an InputStream requires more memory as it has to buffer the
>   whole file.

I therefore wrote approximately this:

```
opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
rows = sheet.rowIterator();
if (rows.hasNext()) {
Row row = rows.next();
    System.out.println(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
}
```

However that results in a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` for a sheet with more than approximately 10000 rows.

I was hoping that iterating only lazily loads those rows that are to be read, like a stream.

How can I get around memory issues with large Excel files? Can I read lazily with Apache POI?

Answer (score 2):

POI offers an eventmodel API that should handle lazy loading. More details can be found at [POI documentation pages about eventmodel](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api) and [other streaming options](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html).