# In my application not getting proper row number or value .(Apache poi)

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

In this application,I am reading xlsx file by using apache-poi ,but I am not getting only row number , it is giving some other data also, please check my code and output.

This is my code:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // c => cell
        System.out.println("The Value of Row is : "+attributes.getValue("r"));
        if(name.equals("c")) {
            // Print the cell reference
            // Figure out if the value is an index in the SST
            String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
            if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                nextIsString = true;
            } else {
                nextIsString = false;
            }
        }
```

When I am printing the row number by using below line, I am getting below output.

```
System.out.println("The Value of Row is : "+attributes.getValue("r"));
```

output is :

```
The Value of Row is : null The Value of Row is : 1 The Value of Row is : A1 The Value of Row is : null The Value of Row is : B1 The Value of Row is : null The Value of Row is : C1 The Value of Row is : null The Value of Row is : D1
The Value of Row is : null
The Value of Row is : E1
The Value of Row is : null
The Value of Row is : F1
The Value of Row is : null
The Value of Row is : G1
The Value of Row is : null
The Value of Row is : H1
The Value of Row is : null
The Value of Row is : I1
The Value of Row is : null
The Value of Row is : J1
The Value of Row is : null
The Value of Row is : AMD1
The Value of Row is : AME1
The Value of Row is : AMF1
The Value of Row is : AMG1
The Value of Row is : AMH1
The Value of Row is : AMI1
The Value of Row is : AMJ1
The Value of Row is : 2
The Value of Row is : A2
The Value of Row is : null
The Value of Row is : B2
The Value of Row is : null
The Value of Row is : C2
The Value of Row is : null
The Value of Row is : D2
```

How can I get the row numbers only ? 
1,2,3,4,5,6,..... like that?

and

How can I get total number of columns and number of Rows ?

Comment: That doesn't look like POI, it looks like standard Java SAX parsing.

Comment: ok.... i need only row numbers, how can i get only row numbers ?

Comment: Row numbers of what? Cell? Simple! `someCell.getRow()`

Comment: how can i get someCell

Comment: if i have 10 rows in my xlsx file , i want row numbers like row 1,2,3,4,.....(not depending on cell)

Answer (score 2):

As already stated in comments, this is not the default way reading a Excel sheet with apache poi. Please read https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html. Especially https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator.

For your sax.ContentHandler code:

The XML of a Excel sheet looks like:

```
...
<sheetData>
 <row r="1">
  <c r="A1">
   <v>1</v> 
  </c>
  <c r="B1">
   <v>2</v> 
  </c>
 </row>
...
```

As you see, there are different elements, not only rows and the "r" attribute has different meanings within those elements. Within element "v" it is null.

So you must first check if you have a row element:

```
...
if(name.equals("row")) { 
   System.out.println("The Value of Row is : "+attributes.getValue("r"));
 }
```

But, as stated above, I don't know if this is really the best way for you.

Edit:

As from you comment if you have up to a million rows, then using sax.ContentHandler code will really be a good approach. So to your concrete question, as i said:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // c => cell
        if(name.equals("row")) {
             System.out.println("The Value of Row is : "+attributes.getValue("r"));
        }
...
```

Comment: in my application i am dealing with large files , that contain's 1000000 rows.

Comment: is there any method to get number of columns

Comment: @honey1: Sorry but this is not the best place teaching you XML parsing. Try reading and understanding http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api. Ask concrete questions with concrete code if you are stuck. Hint: a *.xlsx file is simply a ZIP archive. You can unzip it using default ZIP software. Then have a look at the *.xml files which are stored in that ZIP archive.

Comment: Thank you .... i have another doubt  ,how can i find number of columns from my code ?

Comment: is there any other way to read large xlsx files by using other api's ?

Comment: @honey1: No, in my opinion the event driven parsing approach of apache poi will be the best approach. But using this needs knowledge in event driven SAX-XML parsing. This knowledge you must get somehow. And it is to much handling in one question here.

Comment: @ Axel Richter :How can i find number of rows and Columns from my code ? is there any method to find ?

Answer (score -1):

That code you provided seems to be SAX parsing instead of Apache POI. One of the ways you can get the row number using POI (code is in Java 7):

```
InputStream excelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("path to path to excel/xlsx file");

try(XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFileToRead);){
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // first sheet
Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator(); // rows iterator
...

while(rows.hasNext()){  
    XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
    int rowNum = row.getRowNum(); // Get the row number

    // Reading cell values
    Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();        
    while (cells.hasNext()){
        cell = (XSSF) cells.next();

        if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" ");
        }
        else if(cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
        }else{
                //handle the rest etc.
        }
    }

    ...................

}

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: in my application i am reading large file , so when i am using this way ,i am getting out of memory exception.

Comment: Check this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065941/how-to-lazily-read-big-excel-2007-files-with-apache-poi

Comment: i tried this, i am getting exception : Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)